# What happens when Reaper loses sight of his Shadow Step destination?

Tags: overwatch

Let's say a Reaper has already started teleporting with his Shadow Step, and a Mei places a wall right in front him. What happens to the teleport?

Comment: I would assume that he would TELEPORT and not MOVE to the destination.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He still teleports.

Once started, the teleportation cannot be stopped and line of sight does not matter.

On the other hand, if Mei places an icewall at Reaper's destination, he will appear on top of the wall instead.

Comment: `cannot be stopped` does that mean if you use for example Lucio rightclick he will not get interrupted? Or are you just refering to line of sight.

Comment: @Pasoe I mean that you, playing as reaper, can't stop mid-shadowstep.

Comment: I'm confused... So nothing happens or he teleports? your 2nd phrase fully contradicts your answer.

Comment: @Zaibis Once Reaper starts teleporting, he does not need to maintain LoS to the targeted area -- he will reach there anyway.

Comment: "What happens when Reaper loses sight of his Shadow Step destination?" -> "Absolutely nothing." This reads to me as He won't port. And thats not true, since what happens is, he teleports anyway.